# Windows System Restore - Exceptions?

Tags: windows, system-restore, exceptions

Bit of an unusual question and one which I think I know the answer to already but thought I would throw it out here to see if anyone else has any ideas.

We operate and install security products for home users, and one concern is that third parties (see - children) could revert to a System Restore point and remove our software. Are there any ways that you know of to add exceptions to what Windows will restore? Alternatively could there be a way to leave a file which Windows will not overwrite which we could in turn use to launch a reinstall after the restore is completed?

Utterly weird I know - I'll be shocked if the answer is "yes" but figured it was worth a shot :)

Thanks!
Foxed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, System Restore is meant to RESTORE to a previous state (atleast, startup programs, registry wise. It will leave behind files on the drive.) Hence System Restore selectively restoring stuff does not look likely.

And if the parents give the children admin rights on the PC, then System Restore will be the last thing they will do if they wanted to remove your software. Better option will be uninstall Fast & simple :).

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought. Shame there isn't a way to seperately password protect the system restore option. Oh well. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete system restore points made before and right after the installation of your software.

Comment: Hmm answer makes sense but this will surely not go well with the end users.

Comment: Indeed - it does solve the issue but is pretty risky.